# Ubuntu server + Dynamic DNS

Tags: networking, server, dns

I've got a Ubuntu 14.04 server running with an Dynamic DNS client.

I'm using Dynamic DNS because my ISP changes my WAN IP once in a while.

I made a `no-ip.org` DNS name to connect remotely to my server.

If I want to connect from my other Linux device to the Ubuntu server with my `no-ip.org` DNS name. How do I config that in my Linux device?

Just put in the DNS name and it will work? 
Or do I need to do more configuration ?

Comment: Yes, but I want to use a host name, and not an IP-adress.

Comment: Yes I confirm that.

Comment: It does not redirect me to my server. I do think that my DNS does not know adress.no-ip.org = 192.168.1.x

Comment: A notification agent

Comment: Yes, I confirm that.

Comment: Noooo! I asked if you can connect from an outside world using IP. Back to basics: in what network is your "other Linux" machine? And why did you start to use DDNS at all? What is the purpose? From where to where do you need to connect?

Comment: In the same network as my server. But when I take with with me,  I go remote.  It needs to connect to my ''no-ip.org''  hostname. Because the device moves from intern / remote. I want to use the ''no-ip.org'' all the time, so I dont have to chage it when I move.

Comment: I cant connect from outside world using my ''no-ip.org''

Comment: So you have not set up port forwarding on your router, right?

Answer (score 1):

Your Dynamic DNS is actually (almost certainly) pointing at your router not your Ubuntu computer. Even if you run it from a client inside the network, all DDNS can do is point at the public IP.

I assume you have some port-forwards set up on your router to take the connection onto your Ubuntu server. The problem is that most home routers won't do internal redirects. So a local computer (regardless of operating system) will look at the DNS, get your public IP and try to connect. The router won't know how to forward this on.

You have a few options here, depending on what your router lets you do:

- Run a DNS server inside the network (eg on your server) that provides its own interpretation of `youraddress.no-ip.org` that points directly to the right machine (with a local IP).

  In essence, [install BIND and configure it](https://superuser.com/a/246568/30127) to get most of its DNS from your current DNS server but add overrides.

  But then you need your network computers to use this as their DNS server so you'll need your router to specify this computer as the DNS server. Then when another local computer resolves (you might have to refresh its network connection first) it should get the local IP.
- Just override the DNS on each local computer. Most systems allow editing `/etc/hosts` to assign IPs directly to DNS names.
- Get a router that allows internal forwarding. This feature tends to become available in smaller enterprise routers so this isn't a cheap option.

Comment: I understand your point. Option 1) I need a build in DNS server in my Ubuntu server. To redirect my ''myadress.no-ip.org'' adress to the right LAN IP.

or-

Option 2)Edit my DNS settings, set ''myadress.no-ip.org'' = 192.168.1.x:port

Do I understand this right ?

I would go for option 2.

Comment: 2 is much easier for a limited number of machines where you can edit the hosts file. If you have phones and other devices coming into the network that you need to dynamically configure 1 is better.